# critical vulnerabilities in typescript - react project

Tags: npm, snowpack

I have just created a new project using command `npx create-snowpack-app . --template @snowpack/app-template-blank-typescript --force`

There are 11 vulnerabilities that include 4 critical vulnerabilities so I was trying to fix that using following commands `npm audit fix`, `npm audit fix --force` and by updating each dependency separately as by `npm install request@latest` and so on.

If you have any idea how to fix that vulnerabilities I would be very grateful.

**There is following audit report:**

$ npm audit

## npm audit report

request  *
Severity: moderate
Server-Side Request Forgery in Request - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-p8p7-x288-28g6
Depends on vulnerable versions of tough-cookie
fix available via `npm audit fix`
node_modules/request
node-gyp  <=7.1.2
Depends on vulnerable versions of request
node_modules/node-gyp
@npmcli/run-script  1.1.1 - 1.8.6
Depends on vulnerable versions of node-gyp
node_modules/@npmcli/run-script
@npmcli/arborist  <=2.10.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of @npmcli/metavuln-calculator
Depends on vulnerable versions of @npmcli/run-script
Depends on vulnerable versions of pacote
node_modules/@npmcli/arborist
snowpack  2.12.2-pre.0 || 2.18.0 - 3.0.0-rc.2 || 3.0.7 || 3.2.0-pre.1 - 3.2.0-pre.3 || >=3.3.0-pre.1
Depends on vulnerable versions of @npmcli/arborist
Depends on vulnerable versions of esinstall
Depends on vulnerable versions of pacote
Depends on vulnerable versions of skypack
node_modules/snowpack
pacote  11.1.5 - 11.3.5
Depends on vulnerable versions of @npmcli/run-script
node_modules/pacote
@npmcli/metavuln-calculator  <=1.1.1
Depends on vulnerable versions of pacote
node_modules/@npmcli/metavuln-calculator

tough-cookie  <4.1.3
Severity: moderate
tough-cookie Prototype Pollution vulnerability - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-72xf-g2v4-qvf3
fix available via `npm audit fix`
node_modules/tough-cookie

vm2  *
Severity: critical
vm2 Sandbox Escape vulnerability - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-cchq-frgv-rjh5
vm2 Sandbox Escape vulnerability - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-g644-9gfx-q4q4
fix available via `npm audit fix`
node_modules/vm2
esinstall  0.4.0-pre.1 - 1.1.7
Depends on vulnerable versions of vm2
node_modules/esinstall
skypack  >=0.2.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of esinstall
node_modules/skypack

11 vulnerabilities (7 moderate, 4 critical)

To address all issues, run:
npm audit fix

**Mine package.json is as following:**

{
"scripts": {
"start": "snowpack dev",
"build": "snowpack build",
"test": "echo "This template does not include a test runner by default." && exit 1",
"format": "prettier --write "src/**/*.{ts,js}"",
"lint": "prettier --check "src/**/*.{ts,js}""
},
"dependencies": {
"canvas-confetti": "^1.2.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@snowpack/plugin-typescript": "^1.2.1",
"@types/canvas-confetti": "^1.0.0",
"@types/snowpack-env": "^2.3.3",
"prettier": "^2.2.1",
"snowpack": "^3.3.7",
"typescript": "^4.2.4"
}
}

**node version: v18.16.1**

**npm version: 9.5.1**